# API Perfromance testing tool - JMeter or JUnit?

Tags: java, junit, jmeter, performance-testing, web-api-testing

i am working on some performance testing task. The main goal is to compare duration of old NCP protocol calls againts new REST API calls. I have this scenario:

1. Client has an authenticated session
2. Client access protected resource

I have to create two variants:

a) **One-by-one variant**: The question is: How long does it take to perform 2000 requests sent one by one?

b) **Concurrent variant**: The question is: How long does it take to perform 2000 Request which are sent concurrently (300 Threads ideal)

I dont know the best way to solve this problem. My idea is:

a) Creation of 2000 Http clients -> Each client sends HTTP Post with credentials in body -> Each client sends HTTP GET and get the response (I will measure the time between sending the GET request and getting a response for each iteration and Sum it.

b) Creation of 2000 Httpclients -> Use executor service with fixed thread pool (300) -> each thread will perform sending get request.

Is there any other way? I know that Jmeter is a great tool but i am not sure that this scenario could by performed on Jmeter. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe postman has some of the functionality you require?

Comment: I was looking for some solution, but Postman doesnt provide concurrent solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second variant: you need to determine what is you targeted throughput (**TP**). 2000 request per hour? Per minute? Per second? Once you get the TP, and a **guesstimate** for the scenario response time (**RT**), you could estimate the number of VUsers using the Little's Law. Alternatively, you can use a [calculator](https://ubikloadpack.com/virtual-users-computer.php) to determine that number.

Jmeter provides a mechanism to submit this workload (scenarios) by using [Arrivals Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ArrivalsThreadGroup/). This TG will instantiate the number of threads needed to sustain the targeted TP.

Be aware that there is possibility that you might not reach the **TP** goal due to:

1. the SUT does not have the **capacity** to handle the load
2. a **bottleneck** (resource saturation) somewhere in the environment
3. the client (JMeter) does have enough resources to produce the load

Answer (score 0):

JUnit itself doesn't provide any multithreading logic, you will have to construct the HTTP requests yourself (or with a 3rd-party library like [RestAssured](https://rest-assured.io/)) and then execute them using i.e. [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) or [jmh](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) and then come up with something for results analysis.

[JMeter has everything out of the box](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right/) so you won't need to write a single line of code, [reporting is also included](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html), it might be not that CI friendly as JMeter .jmx scripts are XML but on the other hand you will get nice [protocol metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) and ability to correlate increasing load with increasing response time